# Why Android Studio stop button remains active after running tests?

Tags: android, android-studio

This happens every time I run a test as long as I remember (Android Studio 2+, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2)

[image: here's a picture].

Sometimes the stop button even shows multiple processes. Also it doesn't matter how many times I click the stop button, it will never work (it does stop the test but the button remains in active state).

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a bug in Android Studio. I have found that it was reported previously on Google Issue Tracker with ID 64031765 and is not fixed yet.

Comment: No, that can't be true. I wrote this one like a month ago. And it's a completely different question and bug. There are many bugs in Android Studio.

Comment: It might be because of what the commentator there said, because of "context for links". However, there is not much context about a bug report page without a responses on it.

Comment: There can be no other answers to this kind of questions. Should we not answer them at all?